# Combine between parallel rows only, in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Given two tables with different rows and values,how can I combine this two tables so the first row of the first table will be combined in a new row with the first row of the second table and so on.. The requirement is that unlike Cartesian product, only the parallel rows will be combined together on the new table.
I am working with PL/SQL Developer

For example(the values are just an example as well):

```
 Table 1:
LongId
  100
  200
  300

Table 2: 
   Id
    1
    2
    3

 The new table:
     Id LongId
     1    100
     2    200
     3    300
```

Comment: Does table 1 contain a field that determines the order of rows?

Comment: I don't see any [PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info). Perhaps you meant [PL/SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info)?

Comment: That's what I meant.I edited it,thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT id, longid 
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, 
         row_number() over( order by LONGID ) as XXX
  FROM table1 t
) 
JOIN (
  SELECT t.*, 
        row_number() over( order by id) as XXX
  FROM table2 t
)
USING ( xxx )
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba9b1/5

```
| ID | LONGID |
|----|--------|
|  1 |    100 |
|  2 |    200 |
|  3 |    300 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` on both tables and then use that to join on.

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.longid
FROM
  (SELECT table1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY longid) AS rn
  FROM table1) t1
JOIN
  (SELECT table2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM table2) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: Thank you, though PL/SQL specifically had a problem with the syntax, it underlined the comma before ROW_NUMBER() and said it expected FROM